# Where can I find Edward I's document that uses the term "holocaustum"?

Tags: middle-ages

Some time ago I viewed a medieval document written in the reign of Edward the First of England. It gave reference to the word *holocaustum*. I cannot find this document and have in talks debated the fact of its existence. I did see this document online and debated its Latin meaning with others at the time.  Where can I find this document?

Comment: Seems like you're thinking of [Richard of Devizes'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_of_Devizes) account of the coronation of Richard I, (not Edward I).

Comment: I doubt very much if you read a medieval document. https://www.britannica.com/story/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-holocaust

Answer (score 2):

The [Oxford English Dictionary (1928)](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.147246/page/n347/mode/2up?view=theater), preceding and thus uncoloured by WW2, attests no usage prior to about 1497 except for Biblical references circa 1250  reference in **Genesis** and **Exodus**; and attests no variations other than **holocaustal** and **holocaustic**.

[image]

Comment: If I'm reading the question right, the references in question would likely have been in Latin (or perhaps Norman French), not English.

Comment: In fact, it looks like this entry is saying up at the top that the word "holocaustum" was used in 12th Century AD late Latin. I think that's the same spelling as was used in the question.